# Разворачивание / сворачивание окна при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c++, qt

При нажатии на кнопку программа должна разворачивать экран в полный размер, а при втором нажатии брать исходный размер. Делаю вот так, но оно не работает, выводит

> QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::resize(winsize) in..\Carsharring_files\mainwindow.cpp:29
> QObject::connect: (sender name: 'maximize')
> QObject::connect: (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

(в mainwindow.cpp)

```
    QSize winsize = QWidget::size(); // исходный размер окна
    QObject::connect(ui->maximize, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showFullScreen()));
    QSize fullsize = QWidget::size(); // размер фулл экрана
    if(winsize == fullsize)
    {
        QObject::connect(ui->maximize, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(resize(winsize)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(ui->maximize, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
      if (isFullScreen())
        showNormal();
      else
        showFullScreen();
    });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В корне неверная запись

```
QObject::connect(ui->maximize, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(resize(winsize)));
```

Начиная с того что сигнал и слот имеют разные сигнатуры и заканчивая тем что вы указываете переменные, хотя там должны быть типы параметров

Чтобы подобная чушь даже не компилировалась, используйте так называемый [новый синтаксис](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax/ru)